# Powering 2 dc motors.

Tags: power-supply, dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm just trying to work out the rules for this. I have 2x 9v motors running through an L293dne which may run together, one at a time, and/or, at different speeds using PWM.

I'm thinking an 18v battery with a 9v buck converter on each circuit would do it but can someone confirm this please?

Is there a better way?

Many thanks in advance.

Phil.

Comment: Where will you be using your 2 DC motors? Will they move themselves like a car or will they be stationary and moving something else.

Comment: Hi Harry. Thanks for the reply. It is a tracked tank platform. There will be a raspberry pi, servo, sensors and the 2 motors. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Okay, fine, I'll be more specific. Will you use batteries or is the mains voltage available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[L293dne](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf) has 4 outputs. I assume 2 of them goes to one motor and the other 2 to another motor.

I'm not sure why you want 18 V stepped down to 9 V, unless you are using 18 V batteries (a schematic would've helped). You can use 12 V batteries and step them down to 9 V. Or use 3x lithium cells (3.7×3 = 11.1 V) and step that down to 9 V.

Or you can use solar cells together with some super capacitors (some tens of Farads @ 9 V).

You can also just use some 9 V batteries in parallel and get rid of a step down regulator all together.

As long as you're feeding the L293dne with 9 V you'll be alright.

Comment: Just so I understand. If I were to have one 9v battery running both motors, they would both only get 4.5v? Or is that not how it works?

Comment: I can't answer that question because you haven't shown any schematic. But if you've connected them in a way that *makes sense* then they will both get 9 V.

Comment: Thanks. This is my first electronic build so my apologies for no documentation. I'll try to draw out my idea and post it. I do appreciate your patience:)